# CMake OUTPUT_NAME is not handled in KDevelop

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop

I have the simple project below, with the main goal giving the executable name explicitly, rather than by default. It works fine with native Makefiles, but when I generate KDevelop project file under Ubuntu 14.04, and attempt to run the binary, I receive the error message:

```
It doesn't seem like .../main is an executable at all.
```

The executable file with the explicit name is in the right place, but the system is looking for an executable with the default name. If I comment out the set_target_properties lines, everything works fine. KDevelop is looking for the default binary, and finds is, because it is not renamed.
So, I conclude that somehow the cooperation between CMake and KDevelop
misses the fact that the executable name is given explicitly, rather than using the default. OK, I can live with the default name, but how can I find out the details to report a bug? And, to Cmake or Kdevelop team?

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_SRCS
    "*.h"
    "*.cpp"
)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(
    main
    ${MY_SRCS}
)
set_target_properties(
    main
    PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME MyMain
    )
```

Comment: Before filing a bug, use the latest versions CMake 3.4.1 and KDevelop 4.7.2. Maybe this is already fixed. Ask either of the two projects. If they find out, that the issue is within the other project, the'll let you know. Difficult to guess without having a look into the code. Though, it is kind of not well suited on stackoverflow :-)

Comment: @usr1234567 Well, I am simply developing my project. I found this bug and I guessed someone can advice how can I find out more details for submitting a bug report. I think this part suited on SO. Sorry if not.

Comment: I confirm this bug on KDevelop HEAD. And yes, it is our bug, i think. Feel free to open bug report on this on http://bugs.kde.org/